# Traefik proxy to docker containers yields 404 not found for all subdomains

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to set up a set of containerized apps running on a single ubuntu server. I want each to run on their own subdomain, and use Traefik to proxy the requests to each container based on the domain. My SSL cert is a wildcard cert covering the domain and all subdomains. My issue is that I have not been able to see the apps when I navigate to what I think should be the correct subdomains.

Here is the toml config for the primary Traefik container (pulled from docker hub, btw):

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]

[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"

[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"

[entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "myemail@gmail.com"
storage = "/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = false

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.mydomain.com"
  sans = ["mydomain.com"]

[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "digitalocean"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

And the docker-compose.yml for the Traefik container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7.9
    #command: --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
    environment:
      - DO_AUTH_TOKEN
    networks:
      - default
```

Here's an example of one of the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile files for one of the apps I'm trying to run off of a subdomain:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  servicename:
    build: .
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.backend=servicename"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:servicename.domain.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_default"
      - "traefik.port=8001"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik_default
networks:
  traefik_default:
    external:
      name: traefik_default
```

Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM ruby:2.0.0

# Copy project
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 8001/tcp

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8001"]
```

The containerized app works fine run off of Traefik but I haven't been able to get it wired up yet. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Comment: *I have not been able to see the apps when I navigate to what I think should be the correct subdomains*. Hi, when you are reporting a problem like this it is usually useful to tell in no particular order 1) steps to reproduce  2) what you expected to see 3) what you actually saw. Sometimes the reader can guess that from the information provided, but often not. In your particular case we can argue that you to some extent covered 1 and 2, but 3 is very prominently missing. Do you see any errors? What are they? Did you enable debug logging, what relevant info is in the logs?

Comment: Hi Andrew, what I actually saw was Traefik's stock plaintext "404 page not found" page. Page is redirecting to https per the spec. SSL certs also appeared to be working; browser listed the page as secure for the primary domain (but not for the subdomains, unfortunately). Primary domain and subdomains all had the same 404 page. Stopping the Traefik container

Comment: 404 means that your [match rule](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#matchers) cannot match your url. This is the direction to dig into. Also looking at the dashboard might help (to see created backends / frontends)

Comment: Hi Ashworth, if you enable `debug = true` in your `traefik.toml` you should see some things that may indicate what's going wrong. 

I'd also highly recommend using the `containous/whoami` image when debugging

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually solved the problem by uncommenting out the command: --docker in the compose file. I'm not sure why but commenting out that line introduced the bug I was describing